# Python/Pandas: Unit testing with hypothesis - reproducing falsifying example

Tags: python, pandas, debugging, python-hypothesis

Using the `hypothesis` library for unit testing, I am wondering how I can reproduce a falsifying example `pd.DataFrame`?

The output looks like this:

```
Falsifying example: test_data_frame_data(
    data=                            sec_1  sec_2  sec_3
    2020-01-01 00:00:00.000001    0.0   -0.0    0.0
    2020-01-01 00:00:00.000000    0.0   -0.0    0.0
    2020-01-01 00:00:00.000257    0.0   -0.0    0.0
    2020-01-01 00:00:00.000258    0.0   -0.0    0.0
    2020-01-01 00:00:00.000261    0.0   -0.0    0.0
    ...                           ...    ...    ...
    2020-01-01 00:00:01.526858    0.0   -0.0    0.0
    2020-01-01 01:00:01.065796    0.0   -0.0    0.0
    2020-01-01 01:00:01.065797    0.0   -0.0    0.0
    2020-01-01 01:01:01.065795    0.0   -0.0    0.0
    2020-01-01 00:01:01.000020    0.0   -0.0    0.0

    [300 rows x 3 columns],
)
```

`Hypothesis` didn't print a `seed` or a hint to `@reproduce_failure`.

I simply would like to use the falsifying example to debug my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a hint on the hypothesis GitHub issues page (https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/issues/2584). Credits to @Zac-HD.

First solution:
Put `@settings(print_blob=True)` before a test. This will ensure that you'll get a hint how to reproduce a potential error.

Second solution:
Register a settings profile (e.g. in your `conftest.py`):

```
from hypothesis import settings
settings.register_profile(name="dev", max_examples=20, print_blob=True)
```

All about `settings` can be found in the official docs: https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/settings.html